# IIS 6.0 not sending Expired header though I have turned it on

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

My website is hosted on Windows server 2003, IIS 6.0. The website is developed on ASP.net, with Microsoft Framework 3.5

I have set the content expiry to 12 hours for the complete site using the following settings :

IIS Manager->Site->Properties->HTTP Headers->Enable Content Expiration->Expire After->12 Hours(s)

The Problem is that when i load the site, Expiry header is not being sent with the site. can any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 6 will only add this header to **static content**, e.g. anything not mapped to the asp.net handler (css, js, images, etc).  Are you not seeing the header at all, or just not seeing it on your asp.net dynamic content/pages?

Comment: Hey Nick thanks, i checked it out. Yslow shows that I have expires header with every request besides the js files that are fetched from google and addthis.
but when i use wfetch, it shows no expires header

Comment: @Umair - If you can, use firebug when possible, then you can see the actual list of headers for each request very easily with the net panel.  It's free and invaluable :) http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: firebug also doesnt show any expires header with any of my stuff

Answer (score 1):

When using "Expire After" option in IIS 6.0; IIS 6.0 doesn't send the "Expires" header, it instead sends the "Cache-Control" header to mark cache duration of static content on the client side.

If content should expire after 12 hours(12 hours * 3600 seconds = 43200 seconds), the following response header will be sent back.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Cache-Control: max-age=43200
...
```

IIS 6.0 will use the "Expires" Header if you set the exact date on which contents should expire.

Comment: where shall I use these lines? as there is .htaccess for asp.net applications

Comment: @Umair the fragment above is HTTP response which the web server sends for a request.

Comment: well with PHP I can add a cache control header within the .htaccess file, I want to know how to do this with ASP.net + IIS 6.0.

Comment: @Umair for static resources you can use the IIS 6.0 ContentExpiration settings to enable caching.

For full control over caching use ASP.NET Caching Features; using HttpResponse.Cache property the HttpCachePolicy class can be manipulated to add caching features. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28VS.71%29.aspx for details.